# Knockout Html binding

Tags: html, model-view-controller, knockout.js, binding

I'd bound my model

```
&lt ; input type=&quot ; radio &quot ; name=&quot ;&quot ; &gt ;
```

with the view model of razor engine file.

** I've separated the tags just to show how the html codes were saved in the original format.

When the above data get's displayed over the view, the data is shown as "< input type="radio" name="" />".

The knockout tag that I use at the cshtml page is "<label data-bind = "html: XYZ"></label>".

I want to know why the above data reflects as a string message rather than an html control?

Comment: Could you create a sample jsFiddle that shows your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the string you have provided is correct, I would say it is because of the `whitespace` between `<` and `input`. Make it `<input`. Secondly, depending on how you are quoting within the html to be rendered, you'll need to escape some of the `"` or change them to `'`.

### Viewmodel

```
vm={
html1: "C<input type=\"radio\" name=\"\" />",
html2: "D<input type='radio' name='' />",
html3: "Your example has whitespace causing it to be invalid HTML: < input type='radio' name=''/>"}
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

### Html

```
<body>
  With escaped double quotes <label data-bind="html: html1"></label>
  <br/>
  With single qoutes <label data-bind="html: html2"></label>
  <br/>
  <label data-bind="html: html3"></label>
</body>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/a4Ytf/) for working example of the above.

Comment: The above html string comes from the database when the page gets loaded. I've already called up ko.binding once at the end of the javascript. So If I'm trying to bind an html string do I need to bind my view model once again?

Comment: Depends on how you are setting the value of the container that is holding the `html` string. Any changes to the viewmodel observable values would reflect in the UI after ko.applyBindings, assuming you are using the correct value change syntax: `XYZ('some new html string')`. If you are binding  html that also contains data-binds, then you would need to do separate ko.applyBindings against those.